# Using bootstrap dropdowns in SlickGrid column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slickgrid

In an application that uses Boostrap (3.0) and SlickGrid, i am trying to add a bootsrap dropdown to the column.

```
var columns = [                    
    {id:"rowNumber", name:"", field: "", editor:Slick.Editors.Text, formatter:RowNumberFormatter, behavior:"select", cssClass:"cell-selection", width:40, cannotTriggerInsert:true, resizable:false, unselectable:true, sortable:false},
    {id:"A", name:"X", field: "A", editor:Slick.Editors.Text, sortable:false, width:120},
    {id:"B", name:"Y", field: "B", readonly:true, width:120,
        formatter: linkFormatter = function (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
             var a = 
                '<div class="dropdown">' +
                '  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Action</a>' +
                '  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">' +
                '      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>' +
                '      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>' +
                '      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>' +
                '      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>' +
                '  </ul>' +
                '</div>    ';
             return a;
        }
    }
];
```

However it's not working. My guess is that boostrap binding (magic) should be applied after HTML is generated by a formatter. How can i do that?

here a jsFiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/kilativ/tEU37/

Comment: I think you need to use the javascript part of the Bootstrap Dropdown, you styled it but it will never open I believe, unless you run the javascript `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` and you probably can't put that inside a formatter though you could inside an editor

Comment: tried calling `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` outside of the formatter without luck

Comment: I've also tried to use asynPostRender to manipulate DOM of the cell on the fly so i can apply html() or append() methods. Still no luck

Comment: Have you tried creating an editor like I suggested? It's a little longer to do but it gives you more flexibility.. you might also have the problem that SlickGrid styling overwrite any Bootstrap styling, if that is the case you have to find out which one gets overwritten and try to compensate

Comment: that would require user to click twice, wouldn't it? once to go into edit mode and another to click on the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual problem is not what you imagine it is... The dropdown does actually work but it's just not showing up front... and trying to change the `z-index` does not seem to help. Now I found a partial solution, it's not enough to fix it but it's enough to see the problem. 
Add this piece of CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    position: fixed;
}
```

and you'll see your menu showing but getting mixed with the rest of the grid, I tried to put all kind of `z-index` through it but can't get it to fully work. I'll have to dig more, but for now it's a start...

**SOLUTION**
So I spent more time on this, the bounty helps hehe, and found a solution for your problem. First of all, you cannot directly do it inside a formatter as the cell can't grow bigger and `z-index` does not help for that matter as you are restricted to the cell size. Instead what you have to do is to create an outside `<div>`, attach it to the body and reposition it with the cell X/Y value, then also make sure the new `<div>` as a `z-index` high enough to be on top of the grid... fine but now the question is how do you trigger the action? Simply by subscribing a function to this event `onActiveCellChanged()`. Taking your example, I moved your code from the formatter to the new function, so I added this piece of code:

```
grid.onActiveCellChanged.subscribe(function(e,args){
    $('#myDrop').remove(); // make sure to remove previous dropdown, you don't want to have 100 after a 100 clicks...
    if(args.cell != 2) {
        return;
    }
    var cellPos = args.grid.getActiveCellPosition();
    var elm = $('<div id="myDrop" class="dropdown" style="position:absolute; z-index:10000;">' +
        '  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Action</a>' +
        '  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">' +
        '      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>' +
        '      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>' +
        '      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>' +
        '      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>' +
        '  </ul>' +
        '</div>    ');
    $('body').append(elm);
    elm.css('top', cellPos.top + 5);
    elm.css('left', cellPos.left + 5);
    $('#myDrop.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#myDrop').addClass('open'); // make sure to open the dropdown, delayed so it really open after it's fully created
    }, 50);

});
```

And I was going to remove your formatter but since you have some random integer value, I action replaced with this piece of code:

```
formatter: linkFormatter = function (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    return 'Action';
}
```

I'm not sure if the edit of the `jsFiddle` I made is only temporary but here is the link anyway: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tEU37/68/) 

Also note that you could call the `unsubscribe(fn)` as well but I didn't find it necessary as dropdown seem to go away without it. You can find the list of available SlickGrid events you can subscribe here [wiki/Grid-Events](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Events)

Comment: Looks great... in chrome.. turns out even my original code doesn't render in IE which is a different problem... but you solved what i asked, thanks!